# Checkbox is not resetting itself on a re-render

Tags: reactjs, checkbox

I have a select drop down menu, and once an item is selected, a checkbox shows up, my problem is that if for example, I select "Robot1" and I check its checkbox, but then I decide to select "Robot2", when I do that the checkbox stays checked. I have tried added a state just for the checkbox (althought I dont think thats necessary, since the `setSelectedRobot` gets triggered and that triggers a re-render anyway...?!), I have also tried using the `checked` prop and the `defaultChecked` prop, but I could not get the checkbox to reset itself when a different option is selected.

```
const robotToAdd = { 
                     name: "", someBoolean: false 
                   }
const robots = [
                 {name: "Robot1", someBoolean: false},
                 {name: "Robot2", someBoolean: false},
                 {name: "Robot3", someBoolean: false},
                 {name: "Robot4", someBoolean: false}
               ]

function Component() {
  const [selectedRobot, setSelectedRobot] = useState({});
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <select onChange={(e) => { 
          const robot = robots.find(robot => robot.name === e.target.value);
          setSelectedRobot(robot)
      >
        <option>Choose a robot:</option>
        {robots.map(robot => 
           <option key={robot.name} value={robot.name}>{robot.name}</option>
        )} 
      </select>

      {Object.keys(selectedRobot).length > 0 && (
        <input checked={checked} 
               type="checkbox" 
               onChange={(e) => {
                 robotToAdd.someBoolean = e.target.checked
                 setChecked(e.target.checked)
               }
        />)
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a react key to the input that changes when a new robot is selected. When the key changes then react will mount a new element.

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [selectedRobot, setSelectedRobot] = useState({});

  return (
    <>
      <select
        onChange={(e) => {
          const robot = robots.find((robot) => robot.name === e.target.value);
          setSelectedRobot(robot);
        }}
      >
        <option>Choose a robot:</option>
        {robots.map((robot) => (
          <option key={robot.name} value={robot.name}>
            {robot.name}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>

      {Object.keys(selectedRobot).length > 0 && (
        <input
          key={selectedRobot.name} // <-- use robot name as key
          type="checkbox"
        />
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit checkbox-is-not-resetting-itself-on-a-re-render]

If you wanted to keep the checked state then simply reset the `checked` state back to false when a new robot is selected.

```
<select
  onChange={(e) => {
    const robot = robots.find((robot) => robot.name === e.target.value);
    setSelectedRobot(robot);
    setChecked(false);
  }}
>
```

Comment: Adding key by itself did not work, but moving the setChecked(false) to the onChange of select worked and adding a key worked.

Comment: @Darkbound Interesting. Did you try out the code in the codesandbox I linked? It works there with adding a react key alone.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, remove the checked state. On the checkbox, when the event occurs, you take the current `selectedRobot` and set its `someBoolean` field value.

```
function Component() {
  const [selectedRobot, setSelectedRobot] = useState({});

  return (
    <>
      <select onChange={(e) => { 
          const robot = robots.find(robot => robot.name === e.target.value);
          setSelectedRobot(robot)
      >
        <option>Choose a robot:</option>
        {robots.map(robot => 
           <option key={robot.name} value={robot.name}>{robot.name}</option>
        )} 
      </select>

      {Object.keys(selectedRobot).length > 0 && (
        <input checked={selectedRobot ? selectedRobot.someBoolean : false} 
               type="checkbox" 
               onChange={(e) => {
                 setSelectedRobot(robot => ({...robot, someBoolean: e.target.checked}))
               }
        />)
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: That did not work, same behaviour, checkbox stays checked, I think I've tried something similar with the same result